# Is there a way to file watcher on all hard disk drives?

Tags: python, file-watcher, win32con

I have a scrip to detect some files created on Hard disk drive using *`win32file`* API with python

```
from win32file import CreateFile, ReadDirectoryChangesW
import win32con

def Watcher():
        ExtensionScan = ['exe', 'dll', 'vbs', 'com', 'jar']
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001
        path_to_watch = "c:\\"
        hDir = CreateFile(
            path_to_watch,
            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
            win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | 
            win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | 
            win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            None,
            win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
            win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            None
        )
        while True:
            Results = ReadDirectoryChangesW (
                hDir,
                1024,
                True,
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
                win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
                None,
                None
            )
            for Action, File in Results:
                FullPath = "{}\\{}".format(path_to_watch, File).lower()
                Extension = FullPath.split('.')[-1]
                if Action == 1 and Extension in ExtensionScan:
                    Name = FullPath.split('\\')[-1]
                    print({FullPath: {"Name": Name, "Extension": Extension}})
```

This code works, but i want watcher on all hard disk not specific path

> path_to_watch = "c:\"

I have an idea, call *`Watcher(drive="D:\\")`* with a specific drive by threading for all drives like below code :

```
Drives = ["C:\\", "D:\\", "E:\\"]

for i in Drives:
  Thread(target=Watcher, args=(i,).start()
```

but this solution is not good for processor performance

Finally, is there a way build in *`win32file`* for this solution or use my idea ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Watcher(_disk):
        ExtensionScan = ['exe', 'dll', 'vbs', 'com', 'jar']
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001
        path_to_watch = _disk
...

for i in Drives:
     Thread(target=Watcher(i)
```

Comment: Yes i know this solution, but i ask if there is any other clever idea or method build in "win32file" library, anyway, thank you very much

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).